# Only uploading group layers instead of single simple layer when using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

I use the getWebLayerSharingDraft to upload layers online with Python. However, whenever I upload it, the result is always a group layer with a single layer inside. I wonder if it is possible to use Python to upload as a simple layer instead. My code:

```
arcpy.SignInToPortal('https://realtermenergy.maps.arcgis.com', username, password)
gis = GIS('https://mysite.maps.arcgis.com', username, password)
outdir = r"C:\Folder"
sddraft_filename = "name.sddraft"
sddraft_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sddraft_filename)

# Create FeatureSharingDraft and set service properties
sharing_draft = aprxMap.getWebLayerSharingDraft("HOSTING_SERVER", "FEATURE", GroupLayer)
sharing_draft.summary = "This is a layer."
sharing_draft.tags = "tags"

# Create Service Definition Draft file
sharing_draft.exportToSDDraft(sddraft_output_filename)

# Stage Service
sd_filename = "layername.sd"
sd_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sd_filename)
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft_output_filename, sd_output_filename)

# Share layer to portal
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd_output_filename, "My Hosted Services")
```

The funny thing is that the Arcgis Online page is **identical** to layers upload without using python (using the sharing as a weblayer tool on arcgis PRO), yet the layer using python is a group layer, and using the Pro tool is a single one.

Whenever I go to the catalog on arcgis PRO, and search for the layer and bring to the map, it brings as a group layer named GroupLayer, with the layername Layer inside.

How I use a python code and upload a grouped layer?